# "Security" class not found when doing unit testing

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm discovering unit testing with phpunit and I want to test some method inside my service.

Here is my test code to do so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use App\Services\SortingDataSearchedProductService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class SearchedProductTest extends WebTestCase
{

    private $sortingDataSearchedProductService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $container = self::$container;
        $this->sortingDataSearchedProductService = $container->get(SortingDataSearchedProductService::class);
    }

    public function testFindStatusLinkedToGrantedRoles() {
        $grantedRolesList = [];

        $this->sortingDataSearchedProductService->findStatusLinkedToGrantedRoles($grantedRolesList);
    }

}
```

But when I try my test here is what I get:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Form\CpomAf\SearchProductType": argument "$security" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security" but no such service exists.

I think I get this error because the testing is going through the page where the function I want to test is. Here is the service I want to test :

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;


use App\Entity\Custom\SearchProduct;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

/**
 * Class SortingDataSearchedProductService
 * @package App\Services
 */
class SortingDataSearchedProductService
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;


    /**
     * SortingDataSearchedProductService constructor
     * @param Security $security
     */
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * Form Data
     * @param SearchProduct $searchedData
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function findDataOfSearchWithConditions(SearchProduct $searchedData): array
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        $userPermissions = $user->getPermissions();

        return $this->findStatusLinkedToGrantedRoles(
            $userPermissions
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get array of final list of granted roles
     *
     * @param array $userPermissions
     * @return array
     */
    public function findStatusLinkedToGrantedRoles(array $userPermissions): array
    {
        //Getting the list of role linked to status from yaml file
        $permissionStatusList = Yaml::parseFile(dirname(__DIR__).'/../config/roles.yaml');
        $arrayPermissionListStatus = $permissionStatusList[0];

        //Declaration array status list
        $statusList = [];

        //Getting status linked to permissions
        foreach ($userPermissions as $userPermission) {
            if (array_key_exists($userPermission, $arrayPermissionListStatus)) {
                foreach ($arrayPermissionListStatus[$userPermission] as $status) {
                    array_push($statusList, $status);
                }
            }
        }

        //Deleting double values
        return  array_values(array_unique($statusList));
    }

}
```

I understand my error refers to my formtype file but in the service I'm targetting the only thing that links to my form is **$searchedData** which this the data returned by the submission of my form (that I'm not using yet). Hence, I'm not sure why it's going through my form type file and why it doesn't consider Security as a class.

I tried to use MockBuilder like so in my set up but it didn't help. Maybe I'm using unit testing in the wrong way ?

```
$this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface')
           ->disableOriginalConstructor()
           ->getMock();
```

**EDIT**

Here is the content inside my autoload classmap file after I did the dump autoload command :

```
    <?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Collator' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/Collator.php',
    'IntlDateFormatter' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/IntlDateFormatter.php',
    'JsonException' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-php73/Resources/stubs/JsonException.php',
    'Locale' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/Locale.php',
    'NumberFormatter' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/NumberFormatter.php',
    'SqlFormatter' => $vendorDir . '/jdorn/sql-formatter/lib/SqlFormatter.php',
);
```

I if remember correctly it regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project. So it means that security is there isn't it?

Comment: Did you run `composer require security` ?

Comment: Yes I did because I saw a stackoverflow with a similar problem and they did the command. The security bundle was fully installed. Just in case I did it again but I still get the error :s

Comment: Your code is actually trying to setup a functional test.  Not a unit test.  A unit test would involve new'ing your search class and injecting a mocked Security class.  In any event, double check that the Security class was actually installed in the vendor directory.  And run "composer dump-autoload" just to ensure the autoloading was updated.

Comment: THanks a lot for your answer! I see so this means that I have for example in the set up have to declare a new SearchProduct if I understand correctly ? I updated my answer with the content of the autoload classmap file after doing the command. I see that security isn't there so it means that it is normally installed isn't it ?

Comment: Not sure what the classmap is supposed to mean.  By "checking under vendor" I mean to look in the actual vendor directory and verifying the class is actually there.

Comment: Sorry I see, I do have security inside my vendor/symfony directory.